# How do I update my column values in a table over an API in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

I am able to successfully fetch values over an API and display it in a table format. One field of the table is a text type field which I want to update for all the rows with a single button. I am unable to do so . Any help will be appreciated.

This is my update function :

```
update(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this will update entries with PUT
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
        "method": "PUT",
        "headers": {
            
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "accept": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            status: this.state.status
        })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => { console.log(response);
        
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```